# Passing a generic array to a constructor

Tags: java, generics

Is there any way to pass an array of a bounded generic type to the method with an argument of the same generic type without raising ClassCastException?:

```
public class Heap<E extends Comparable>  implements java.lang.Cloneable{

    private java.util.ArrayList<E> list = new java.util.ArrayList<E>();

    public Heap(E[] objects) {
         for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            add(objects[i]);
        }
    }

    private  void add(E newObject){
    ...
    }

    @Override
    protected Heap<E> clone() {
        return new Heap<E>((E[])list.toArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem with this code?

Comment: Where are You getting ClassCastException here? At least provided array elements should implement Comparable interface.

Comment: You forgot to tell us where the exception occurs... it's in clone, correct?

Comment: Casting list.toArray() to E[] raises ClassCastException. All array's elements implement Comparable. I know I can make add public and add each element separately without raising an exception, but I was wondering if there's any solution to this particular situation.

Comment: I want to add that if you never return the type `E[]` to the outside of this class, then there is no need to store the class of `E`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ok with all the unchecked casts that should do it:

```
class Heap<E extends Comparable>  implements java.lang.Cloneable{

    private java.util.ArrayList<E> list = new java.util.ArrayList<E>();
    Class<E> classE;

    public Heap(E[] objects) {
        Class<? extends Object[]> aClass = objects.getClass();
        this.classE = (Class<E>) aClass.getComponentType();
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            add(objects[i]);
        }
    }

    private  void add(E newObject){
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected Heap<E> clone() {
        return new Heap<E>(list.toArray((E[])Array.newInstance(classE, list.size())));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Effective Java by Joshua Bloch (Item 25):

> It is illegal to create an array of a generic type, a parameterized type, or a type parameter. None of these array creation expressions are legal new `List<E>[]`, new `List<String>[]`, `new E[]`.

So use Lists instead of arrays with generics.

Answer (score -1):

```
 return new Heap<E>((E[])list.toArray());
```

No, arrays cannot be type cast (well, only from `Object`).

Use instead:

```
 return new Heap<E>(list.toArray((E[])new Comparable[0]));
```

(Assuming you use bounded type of `Comparable`, otherwise use:

```
return new Heap<E>(list.toArray((E[])new Object[0]));
```

)

This will return an array of type `E[]`.

Comment: New `new E[0]` wont compile as you cannot instantiate generic arrays.

Comment: This code also throws: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;.

Comment: @user2098232 Oh, this happened because you use bounded type, I didn't realize. See edit.